# Is it possible to fix the "cannot find -lgcc" and "cannot find -lgcc_s" error messages when using arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ as a linker?

Tags: c++, cross-compilation, arm

I get the following error messages: ./Downloads/tmp/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux‌​-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s and Downloads/tmp/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-g‌​nueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc 
when I compile a C++ source file on an Ubuntu Linux 16.04 machine using the C++ ARMv6 compiler, arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.6.

- Please  let me caution the reader that I downloaded this compiler rather than installing it with something like sudo apt-get install arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++. *

  Do these errors have anything to do with arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.6 --sysroot or the fact that strace shows collect2's runtime filepath is not resolved or an incorrect bash shell export LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Or, could these errors be caused by another source?

  We are using the arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.6 compiler to cross-compile source files for the Raspberry PI ARM v6 emulator mounted on an SD Card and as a linker for generating executables which load shared objects.

  Please recommend a way to solve the above 2 error messages.

  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried statically linking libgcc_s.a and lbgcc.a with no success.

Comment: @goldilocks, Here is the new Raspberry PI stack exchange question you recommended I ask earlier this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by prefacing -ltestconverter by -L. in the arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.6 linking step.

But now I am getting multiple definitions errors when I run this linking step:

```
/home/Downloads/tmp/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.6 -g  --sysroot=.  Test.o  -o SimpleTester -shared -L. -ltestconverter

./testconverter.so:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
crtbeginS.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): first defined here
./testconverter.so: In function `_init':
:(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
./testconverter.so: In function `_fini':
:(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
crtendS.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
./testconverter.so::(.data+0x4): first defined here
```

How do I  fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I fixed this problem by using an g++-4.6 vintage loader(ld) instead of the  arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.6 compiler and linker. Then, I removed all the loader references to object files and libraries such as crti.o and -lgcc_s.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.